# AngularJS - How to render template AND data from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Alright, I'm pretty new to Angular, spent the last two days trying to find a good way to do this and failed. I'm not sure if the title is good either.

I'm trying to make a simple page with a menu. The person would click a menu link and then the view that's below the menu should render accordingly (without refreshing the whole page of course). Sounds easy.

But the thing is, there's going to be a menu for admins and a menu for regular users, so the menu is loaded through ajax. This is an example of what I get:

```
[
    {
        name: "Manage games",
        templateUrl: "/view/mygames.html",
        url: "/games",
    },
    {
        name: "Weekly Reports",
        templateUrl: "/view/myreports.html",
        url: "/reports"
    },
    {
        name: "Manage Users",
        templateUrl: "/view/users.html",
        url: "/users",
        adminRequired: true
    }
];
```

After the menu is loaded, when a menu element is clicked, I want to get data making an ajax call to the `url` property, and the template to fetch this data to will also be an ajax call to the `templateUrl` property.

So, how is that achievable? Basically what I want is to have a directive/component/whatever, that by default will be empty, not displayed or rendered. But when I click on a element from the menu, I'm going to $broadcast an event with the dataUrl/templateUrl to the directive/component/whatever, and it will make two ajax calls, one two get the data, and another to get the template, after both get done, it will render and appear on the page.

Any way to this, or suggestion to do something similar to this would be greatly appreciated

By the way, I'm using Angular 1.5.7

Comment: Or you could use ngRoute.

Comment: Well I tried using ngRoute but I couldn't get it right. Like, I have the MenuController, and inside it I make the call to get the JSON I showed. After I get the object, I tried using app.config passing the $rootProvider to define routes, but for some reason the function would never get called, and also saw other people having similar problems. Not sure if you can call app.config from inside a promise/controller

Comment: Again, I'm pretty new to Angular so maybe I did something really wrong there

Comment: You can't setup routes in controller. You need to do it in config phase. For that you need to make ajax request using global injector $http service. I could set up everything for you, but I'm a bit lazy at the moment.. But it's quite easy once you load routes. Regarding `url`: it's better to use resolve instruction with some helper service.

Comment: Hmm I guess having the $http as global would solve the problem, I'm not sure how to globally inject but I'm already searching on this. Not sure what  would be a resolve instruction with helper service. I would love any link/information about this topic. Thanks dfsq!

Comment: To get global $http: `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http')`

Comment: Check this demo for how to load routes dynamically: http://plnkr.co/edit/lJJInkPX3E65pz7MQ8w1?p=info Next step is to setup resolve to load data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did some tests here and got it working on my app. I'm going to look how to use resolve to load data next.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this @dfsq, I thought I got everything that I needed but there's something that I can't do with this way. I want the menu to be loaded dinamically as well (in the json there's going to be a name property). So, I can't reuse this data for the MenuController, because I don't have the $rootScope inside the config. Is there a way to achieve this? Or do you suggest another pattern? Of course I can simply make the request again in the MenuController but that's not a pretty solution. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You should use routing (in my example it's the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) for achieving this.
The ui-router has a [resolve](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.ejtunzepv) property that lets you resolve controller dependencies and lets you then inject them into your controller for using them.

Here's a full example that I've made (sorry for the poor ui):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl as vm">
    <menu items="vm.items"></menu>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('gamesCtrl', function(data) {
  this.title = data.title;
}).
controller('reportsCtrl', function(data) {
  this.title = data.title;
}).
controller('usersCtrl', function(data, adminData) {
  this.title = data.title;
  this.removedUsers = adminData.removedUsers;
}).
controller('homeCtrl', function() {
  this.items = [{
    name: 'Manage games',
    state: 'games'
  }, {
    name: 'Weekly Reports',
    state: 'reports'
  }, {
    name: 'Manage Users',
    state: 'users',
    adminRequired: true
  }];
});

app.component('menu', {
  bindings: {
    items: "="
  },
  template: '<div ng-repeat="item in  $ctrl.items"><span ng-click="$ctrl.goToState(item)">{{item.name}}</span></div>',
  controller: function($state) {
    this.goToState = function(item) {
      console.log('redirecting to state:' + item.state);
      $state.go(item.state);
    }
  }
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.
  state('games', {
    url: '/games',
    template: '<div><h1>{{vm.title}}</h1></div>', // use templateUrl..
    resolve: {
      data: function($q) {
        return $q.when({
          title: 'games'
        })
      }
    }, // return injectables who return promises and inject them into your ctrl
    controller: 'gamesCtrl as vm'
  }).
  state('reports', {
    url: '/reports',
    template: '<div><h1>{{vm.title}}</h1></div>', // use templateUrl..
    resolve: {
      data: function($q) {
        return $q.when({
          title: 'reports'
        })
      }
    }, // return injectables who return promises and inject them into your ctrl
    controller: 'reportsCtrl as vm'
  }).
  state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    template: '<div><h1>{{vm.title}}</h1><div>Removed Users:</div><div ng-repeat="user in vm.removedUsers">{{user}}</div></div>', // use templateUrl..
    // return injectables who return promises and inject them into your ctrl
    resolve: {
      data: function($q) {
        return $q.when({
          title: 'users'
        })
      },
      adminData: function($q) {
        return $q.when({
          removedUsers: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
        })
      }
    },
    controller: 'usersCtrl as vm'
  }).
  state('default', {
    url: '/default',
    template: '<h1>This is the default state</h1>'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hzsfqvpm/).

**Remarks**:

- You should use templateUrl instead of template when configurating the states.
- I've used `$q.when` to demonstrate a return of a promise. You will probally use `$http.get\pos`t instead.